# Angular UI-GRID: Loop through array of JSON objects

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid, ui-grid

Please help... I have array of objects, having some attributes and corresponding values. Example: Various types of scores for the group of students. Each score_object has a result, test name (math, english, biology et cetara) and test group name (literature, sciences et cetera).  All the score_objects are placed in a array called scoreArray.

To get student1's first test result, I am just giving static index of the array. e.g., scoreArray[0].score_object.result. Please let me know how can we loop though an array and get corresponding results dynamically.

Problem State: Each student can have so many score_objects within his/her score array. So many test types- couldn't really do static indexing.

Resultant UI should be as follows:

```
      testtype1  testtype2  testtype3
```

Student1    result      result     result
student2    result      result     result
.
.
.

Comment: place your array of objects here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try it with 
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/209_grouping
or 
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/215_treeView

There you can List your Students and then expand the Results of each one?